# How to check if details are from a specific form in php?

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="post"  class=" clearfix no-mar payment-form" action="checkout.php" id="checkoutRevisionProcess">
     <input type="hidden" name="joborderno" id="postsecondrevieworderno" value="%%GLOBAL_postsecondrevisionorderno%%"/>
     <div class="clearfix action-btn-submit">
          <div class="pull-right">
              <a title="Yes" class="btn btn-primary postsecondrevisionyes">PAY</a>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

I want to write an if condition to check if this form has been called or not in php. How do I do this please help.

Comment: You'd have to add another hidden input that contains a unique id for the form.

Comment: @PeterMader I'd really appreciate if you elaborate it with a piece of code. the php code too if possible.

Comment: Please show your form handling code `checkout.php` and explain your problem in more details - how many forms do you have posting to the same endpoint? What is different about them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery and see prevention.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an input with `type="hidden"` to each form and set it's value to the id/name you want to have for that form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="checkout" name="form-id" />
```

But be informed that you shouldn't use that for safety validations since the user would be able to just change the value using a debugger.